# PHP & MySQL web app - Selecting a single field (vs) select * from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-optimization

I am working on converting a prototype web application into something that can be deployed. There are some locations where the prototype has queries that select all the fields from a table although only one field is needed or the query is just being used for checking the existence of the record. Most of the cases are single row queries.

I'm considering changing these queries to queries that only get what is really relevant, i.e.:

```
select * from users_table where <some condition>
```

vs

```
select name from users_table where <some condition>
```

I have a few questions:

1. Is this a worthy optimization in general?
2. In which kind of queries might this change be particularly good? For example, would this improve queries where *joins* are involved?
3. Besides the SQL impact, would this change be good at the PHP level? For example, the returned array will be smaller (a single column vs multiple columns with data).

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: yes, all of them, yes

Comment: Similar(possible duplicate) question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted more than just "Yes"...

- `SELECT *` is "bad practice": If you read the results into a PHP non-associative array; then add a column; now the array subscripts are possibly changed.
- If the `WHERE` is complex enough, or you have `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY`, and the optimizer decides to build a tmp table, then `*` *may* lead to several inefficiencies:  having to use `MyISAM` instead of `MEMORY`; the tmp table will be bulkier; etc.
- `EXISTS SELECT * FROM ...` comes back with 0 or 1 -- even simpler.
- You may be able to combine `EXISTS` (or a suitable equivalent `JOIN`) to other queries, thereby avoiding an extra roundtrip to the server.

Comment: +1 and "accepted" for giving some justifications. Regarding the "select count(*)", does MySQL optimize quer query specifically for it? Is it equivalent to making a "select count(pk_field)"?

Comment: `COUNT(x)` checks `x` for being `NOT NULL`; hence that is potentially slower than simply `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: I should have said `EXISTS SELECT * ...`, not `EXISTS SELECT COUNT(*) ...`.  Yes the `*` (or `1`) is optimal.

Answer (score 2):

If I were to answer all of your three questions in a single word, I would definitely say *YES*.

Comment: @Terminus That's just to avoid the minimum character limit.